# How to select a node having any text inside his descendents using XPath?

Tags: xpath

I have a tag like

```
<a href="xyz.html">
<b>Some text here</b>
</a>
```

if I search the document for

```
//a[text()]
```

the tag is not in the list since link tag has no InnerText directly. how can I match it for an Item with an innerText any where in it's descendents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how can I match it for and Item with
>   an innerText any where in it's
>   descendents?

If by Item you mean an `a` element:

```
//a[.//text()]
```

If your XML tree provider preserves whitespace only text nodes:

```
//a[.//text()[normalize-space()]]
```

The string-value of an element is the concatenation of its descendants text nodes, so you could also use:

```
//a[string()]
```

Or

```
//a[normalize-space()]
```

Answer (score 0):

try: `//a[string(.) = "some text here"]`

(or `//a[contains(string(.), 'some text')]`)

Answer (score 0):

This also should be enough:

`//a//text()`